# Agrupar registros por campo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Se que el título es idéntico a muchas otras preguntas que rondan por acá, pero no se como formularla para que sea diferente, además, las especificaciones de lo que quiero van más allá.

Verán, tengo una tabla llamada **acciones** con **2 columnas:** ***usuario*** y ***fecha.***

Propongamos las siguientes filas:

```
Usuario | Fecha
-------- ---------
enrique | 2018
-------- ---------
juan    | 2012
-------- ---------
enrique | 2013
-------- ---------
juan    | 2014
```

Lo que busco es agrupar solamente el campo usuario de manera que me traiga de la BD los usuarios repetidos pero mostrar a su vez todas las fechas de ese usario que se repite, intenté algo con **GROUP BY** pero no me resultó, me suprime las demas fechas y solo me muestra una. Especificando, quisiera poder hacer algo así a la hora de mostrarlo:

```
Enrique | Accesos
--------|--------
        | 2018
        |--------
        | 2013


Juan    | Accesos
--------|--------
        | 2012
        |--------
        | 2014
```

Cabe acotar que estoy trabajando con php. Les paso por si acaso la consulta con la que intenté hacerlo:

```
$acciones = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM acciones GROUP by usuario") or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de tanto inventar lo he logrado, dejo mi codigo:

```
<?php
    $acciones = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM acciones GROUP by usuario") or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($acciones)){

        $usu = $data['usuario'];

        $subsel = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM acciones WHERE usuario = '$usu'") or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));

        echo "<b>".$usu."</b><br>";

        while ($subdata = mysqli_fetch_array($subsel)){
            echo $subdata['fecha']."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Enhorabuena por conseguirlo. Te animo a que lo resuelvas con un único query a la base de datos, verás como tu código gana en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

```
$acciones = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM acciones GROUP by usuario, fecha") or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Tienes que agrupar por ambas columnas, al agrupar primero por usuario, unificara todos los usuarios repetidos asignando un valor del que no podemos estar seguros en la columna fecha.

Si le dices que agrupe por usuario y después por fecha, conseguirás algo muy cercano a lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Si no vas a realizar ningún cálculo de totales, no es necesario que utilices GROUP BY, con un simple ORDER BY usuario,fecha obtendrás algo parecido a lo que estás buscando.

Cuando hagas el fetch en PHP, muestra el usuario únicamente la primera vez que aparezca y obtendrás la lista que quieres obtener. Sería perfecto si tuvieras identificadores únicos de usuario en vez de sus nombres, ya sabes, dos usuarios podrían llamarse igual y la tabla no sería fiel a la realidad.

Espero haberte ayudado. Si no lo ves del todo claro, coméntamelo y te paso el código de PHP que te lo resolvería:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($mysqli, "
    SELECT usuario,fecha FROM acciones ORDER BY usuario,fecha;
    ") or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
$nombre=null;
$txt=null;
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    if($nombre!=$r['usuario']){
        $nombre=$r['usuario'];
        $txt.=$r['usuario'].'|Accesos';
        $txt.='-----|-----';
    }
    $txt.='  |'.$r['fecha'].'';
    $txt.='  |-----';
}
```

Comment: No quedé del todo claro, echandole cabeza me quedé hasta donde puedo usar order by, pero eso solo me lo ordenaria, no se como llegar a la parte de que el usuario me lo muestre una sola vez.

Comment: @Jalkhov usando consultas sql no puedes hacer que el usuario te lo muestre una sola vez, ya que este puede tener varios accesos, la forma mas simple y flexible es como lo hizo David